# How to configure maven tomcat port in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have a maven web project, when I issue a maven build with this goal > `clean install tomcat:run`, this will launch the tomcat server. Anyhow the server were fail to launch because of this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) on project
>   WebEngineering: Could not start Tomcat: Protocol handler
>   initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
>   :8080 -> [Help 1]

I just realize there were another application were using port 8080, I don't want to lose it. May I know how could I change my current project port number other than 8080?

Answer (score 3):

In `pom.xml`, where you declared the **apache tomcat maven plugin**, you would set or change the port number, Ex:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- or if you want to use tomcat 6.x
    <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    -->
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <!-- http port -->
      <port>9090</port>
      <!-- application path always starts with /-->
      <path>/</path>
      ...
</plugin>
```

See [Run an embeded Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/run-mojo-features.html)

Comment: May also run `mvn -Dmaven.tomcat.port=9090 tomcat:run`
It didn't work because you has configured tomcat7 plugin and run tomcat plugin

Comment: It's working! May I know how could I start debug mode if I execute it from command line? BTW, I must remove the answer you have provided in order to execute this command because maven complaining this > 'Unable to find resource 'org.apache.tomcat.plugin:tomcat6-maven-plugin:pom:2.1' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)'

Answer (score 0):

In `Project Explorer`, on `Servers` tab, expand your server. 
There open the `catalina.properties` file and at the end of the file you can select the port you want to use like:

```
 `bio.http.port=9090`
```

Sorry, that is for VMWare. For Tomcat open the `server.xml` file and edit the port.
There you should have a connector with port = 8080. Just change to another value.

Comment: No, it is not working. I think it has nothing to do with the Tomcat instance in Eclipse because tomcat:run is design to run tomcat inside maven quickly. Somehow there are people configure it to link with the Tomcat instance, but I choose not to do so because I want it to be quick.

Comment: @huahsin68 did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue